# How can I convert a link into a string?

Tags: ruby, string, variables, hyperlink

I have this code:

```
ie1.link(:text, /Exception:/)
```

It is producing an error message which I want include to my report. I use the following method to create reports - http://wiki.openqa.org/display/WTR/HTML+report+class.

The output of each step in the test is described in this line:

```
 def addtoReport(reportName, step, result, description)
```

The description's type is string. I write this code:

```
 h = ie1.link(:text, /Exception:/)
 r.addtoReport(testReport, "check insert", "FAILED", h )
```

But I get the error:

```
E:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.0.0/lib/watir-classic/CLReport.rb:150:in `+': can't convert Watir::Link into String (TypeError)
from E:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-classic-3.0.0/lib/watir-classic/CLReport.rb:150:in `addtoReport'
from file.rb:96:in `<main>'
```

Comment: khris, you're responded favorably in the comments, perhaps it's time to accept an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want the text of the link, you should be using `h.text`.

So either state you want the text attribute of h:

```
h=ie1.link(:text, /Exception:/)
r.addtoReport(testReport, "check insert", "FAILED", h.text )
```

or save the text as h:

```
h=ie1.link(:text, /Exception:/).text
r.addtoReport(testReport, "check insert", "FAILED", h)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `to_s` method? `h.to_s`

```
r.addtoReport(testReport, "check insert", "FAILED", h.to_s )
```

Comment: No, I'm new to ruby, could you explain how to use this method? I try in this way "h.to_s = ie1.link(:text => /Exception:/)", but get error "undefined method `to_s=' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)". I try define it "def to_s end", but it not help. I guess it is not proper defining method